# Create init.d script file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, init.d

I have a sample file with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setting environment

CLASSPATH="."
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:props"
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:cfg"
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:./bin/*"
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:./wslib/*"
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:./oalib/*"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"

# RAM usage settings
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"

# Settings of GC
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2"

# Print of memory usage
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xloggc:./log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution"

# setting config
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS se.highex.ebe.adaptor.Adapter -config cfg/config_gw_ws.xml"

echo $CLASSPATH
echo $JAVA_OPTS

export CLASSPATH
export JAVA_OPTS

java $JAVA_OPTS
```

file is locating in /app/somepath/stpa.sh

how I can create an init.d file for start/stop/restart it?

I found this [tutorial](http://blog.terminal.com/using-daemon-to-daemonize-your-programs/), but after **service stpa start** command there is no any messages in terminal and I think, that my script is not working. But can't find the reason.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English!

**EDIT:**
this is my **stpa** file in /etc/init.d

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: 2345 90 60

name="STPA_WS"
command="/app/STPAdapterPG/stpa_ws.sh"
command_args=""
daemon="/usr/local/bin/daemon"

[ -x "$daemon" ] || exit 0
[ -x "$command" ] || exit 0

daemon_start_args=""
pidfiles="/var/run"
user=""
chroot=""
chdir=""
umask=""
stdout="daemon.info"
stderr="daemon.err"

case "$1" in
    start)
        if "$daemon" --running --name "$name" --pidfiles "$pidfiles"
        then
            echo "$name is already running."
        else
            echo -n "Starting $name..."
            "$daemon" --respawn $daemon_start_args \
                --name "$name" --pidfiles "$pidfiles" \
                ${user:+--user $user} ${chroot:+--chroot $chroot} \
                ${chdir:+--chdir $chdir} ${umask:+--umask $umask} \
                ${stdout:+--stdout $stdout} ${stderr:+--stderr $stderr} \
                -- \
                "$command" $command_args
            echo done.
        fi
        ;;

    stop)
        if "$daemon" --running --name "$name" --pidfiles "$pidfiles"
        then
            echo -n "Stopping $name..."
            "$daemon" --stop --name "$name" --pidfiles "$pidfiles"
            echo done.
        else
            echo "$name is not running."
        fi
        ;;

    restart|reload)
        if "$daemon" --running --name "$name" --pidfiles "$pidfiles"
        then
            echo -n "Restarting $name..."
            "$daemon" --restart --name "$name" --pidfiles "$pidfiles"
            echo done.
        else
            echo "$name is not running."
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;

    status)
        "$daemon" --running --name "$name" --pidfiles "$pidfiles" --verbose
        ;;

    *)
        echo "usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|reload|status>" >&2
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Can you try running `/etc/init.d/stpa start` once to see if the script is getting invoked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not complete the init.d script format, you need to add the content just like the tutorial you mentioned:

```
case "$1" in  
    start)


    #here do something you need when start
    ;;

stop)
    #here do something you need when stop

    ;;

restart|reload)


    ;;

status)

    ;;

*)

    echo "usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|reload|status>" >&2

    exit 1
esac
```